# Using Validators to validate Words in Comments not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to validate Comments in Posts to ensure that there are no bad words used in it.

I have checked about [Writing validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#writing-validators) but it is not working and I am not sure what is the reason.

The badwords.txt location is: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\badwords.txt`

The function lives in the models.py:

```
with open("badwords.txt") as f:
    CENSORED_WORDS = f.readlines()

def validate_comment_text(text):
    words = set(re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split())
    if any(censored_word in words for censored_word in CENSORED_WORDS):
        raise ValidationError(f"{censored_word} is censored!")


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text,])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

***My question:***

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this function to work?

Comment: This is generally not the right way to do it, I would suggest you to use some sentiment analysis library in Python or build a custom model from existing data-set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you lower all censored words list and match word

```
def validate_comment_text(text):
    LOWER_CENSORED_WORDS = list(map(lambda x : x.lower(), CENSORED_WORDS))
    words = set(re.sub(r"[^\w]", " ",  text).split())
    censored_word = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in LOWER_CENSORED_WORDS, words))
    if censored_word:
        raise ValidationError(f"{censored_word[0]} is censored!")
    return text
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation in your code but now when I submit a comment there is no comments going through it is not even showing in the admin

Comment: I tried it but it is not working some indentation error, could you provide some expalanation to it as I am trying to learn from it

Comment: First we lower all censored words then we check each word of comment if the word in censored words then we raise error else return